# Get value from dynamic property

Tags: c#

```
d.GetType().GetProperty("value2").GetValue(d, null);
```

this returns the value of the value2 property inside d.

I want the value of the property inside value2 i.e d.value2.value3.

How should i achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
object e = d.GetType().GetProperty("value2").GetValue(d, null);
object f = e.GetType().GetProperty("value3").GetValue(e, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# 4, simply use the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword to allow run time evaluation of your properties:

```
((dynamic) d).value2.value3;
```

Comment: What is the difference from `d.value2.value3` if you know `value2` and `value3` at compile time(while you were writing your code)?

Comment: If `d` is of a type known by the compiler, using `dynamic` in this case won't be much useful: it will simply defer overload resolution at runtime.

Comment: Suppose `value2` string is available only at runtime(read from an xml file for ex.).

Comment: It's a totally wrong exmaple. U should never use dynamic if you know the name and type of variable. While you should use dynamic is when you don't know or don't care about the type and name or property. Or, if you have different names (dynamic creation of rul using mapping and getting values as an example "localhost/path/to/{someVariable}/status").